# How long does it typically take to make a telescope yourself for the first time?

Tags: telescope

How difficult is it to make a telescope oneself? How much time would it take for a first-timer? What are the typical pitfalls?

Comment: There are really too many unknown variables to give this a good, concise answer. One could write an entire book on this subject (and in fact, I'm sure some have).

Answer (score 1):

Making your own telescope is very do-able given basic working skills. Usually a DOB or Newtonian reflector is a good choice. You can buy a mirror and components all ready to assemble or you can choose to grind your own (which is more difficult). If you have an astronomy club in your area check to see if they can help putting your project together. If not, check online ( Youtube, etc) for guidance. Websites like Edmonds Optics may still be a good choice for components. Once you get all the components together, they can be assembled in a pretty short time. Good Luck!